# Can read but not update a newly created environment variable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, environment-variables

I created a new environment variable to track the status of a possible failure condition, the variable is a simple flag called `FailFlag` that can be set or reset, with values `FlagIsSet` and `FlagIsReset` respectively. To create the environment variable I opened up system environment variables from Control Panel, and added a new system variable called `FailFlag` and assigned it value `FlagIsReset`.

Now, I want to programatically set and reset the flag from my C# program. I attempted this as follows :

```
namespace EnvVars
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FailFlag"); // Here value is seen to be 'FlagIsReset'
            if (value == null)
                System.Console.WriteLine("Failed to read env variable");  
            else
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FailFlag", "FlagIsSet");
        }
    }
}
```

But, if I run my program and then inspect my system environment variables again, I see that `FailFlag` is `FlagIsReset` rather than being `FlagIsSet`, which means that my program failed to update its value. Can you please suggest me a fix?

FWIW, I started Visual Studio *as an administrator*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx)

```
Public method Static member     SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String)  //Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process.
Public method Static member     SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)   //Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process or in the Windows operating system registry key reserved for the current user or local machine.
```

Since the scope of that overload of `SetEnvironmentVariable` is the process, what did you expect?

Try a different [environmentvariabletarget Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx) if you want a different storage scope

Comment: @StraightLine *Try a different environmentvariabletarget Enumeration if you want a different storage scope*

Answer (score 1):

The environment is an inherited *copy* of the parent process' environment. You can't modify the global environment in the way you're trying to do.